# how to return a variable from one shell script to another script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 2 shell scripts called script1.sh (executes on local server ) and script2.sh (executes on remote server which i am passing it to ssh command). and my script1.sh is connecting to unix server and and executing script2.sh as below.

```
declare RESULT=$(sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@1.2.3.4 "bash -s" < ./script2.sh )
```

and script2.sh does some calculations and returns some variable to calling script i.e script1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
declare var1="fgte"
return var1
```

I want to return var1 from script2.sh which is executing on server and should return some value to script1.sh. How can i do that? I need to read the value of var1 in script1.sh. Please help me.

Comment: You can not use return. Use `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use stdout, and print out the result in your `script2.sh` (using `echo` as you've done), and collect it in `script1.sh` e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
result=$(script2.sh $var)
```

This becomes more complex as/when you return multiple values from a child script, and you have to delineate/parse. For a single value, however, it's a simple and pragmatic approach.

Note this is distinct from the shell script *exit code*, which is traditionally used to indicate if your script returned successfully or not.